# Matching bracket selection on gnome-terminal, like Mac OSX terminal

Tags: linux, macos, mac, terminal, gnome

I have recently fallen for a (non obvious) feature of the Mac OSX terminal:

Given a display of some kind of deeply nested text with lots of matching brackets, parenthesis, or quotes (ie. JSON), the user can select the entire text contained by those brackets, parenthesis, or quotes by double clicking on their first occurrence.

For example, given `{foo:{bar:baz}}` I can instantly select `{bar:baz}` by double clicking the curly bracket before `bar`.

How can I bring this feature to my linux terminal? I'd prefer a gnome-terminal solution, but anything that achieves this solution is okay by me.